# Workspace API use OpenTab() to open existing tab using pageReference

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, workspaceapi

I'm opening a tab using workspace API openTab() with pageReference passing some values within state.

Then I want to open the same tab by clicking a different link and passing different parameters. So by using the pageReference how can I open the same tab with these different parameters? I know I can open the tab using URL argument. But it doesnt work in my case!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The reason it does not change is because you will be getting the parameters from state only on `init` and initialised only once and whenever you want to load the same component again with different parameters, `init` will not be invoked again.

You should be using `change` handler on `pageReference` so that you can get the parameters from state whenever its changed. You can check [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation)

Sample:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" description="c:helloTarget component">
    <aura:attribute name="firstname" type="String" />
    <!-- Add an "init" handler to handle the first "v.pageReference" value -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"/>
    <!-- Add a "change" handler to handle all changes to the "v.pageReference" value -->
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"/>
    Hello {!v.firstname}.
</aura:component>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
({
    onPageReferenceChange: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var myPageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
        var firstname = myPageRef.state.c__firstname;
        cmp.set("v.firstname", firstname);
    }
})
```